# Error object property can not be iterated by for loop

Tags: javascript

I often use for loop to iterate JavaScript objects, and have never find a problem until today. 
It astonished me when I am trying to know what properties an Error object have.

```
var e= new Error("testing");

for(var key in e)
  console.log(e[key]);
```

I got nothing, not ouput.
But of course, the following code

```
console.log(e.name);
console.log(e.message);
```

gives intended output:

```
"Error"
"testing"
```

I am not sure what is happening. I tried to Google around but have not find an answer yet. Can some one give me an explanation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript properties can be *enumerable* or *non-enumerable*. Non-enumerable properties are left out of `for-in` loops and most other ways of getting the property names from the object.

You can get an object's own property names, including non-enumerable ones, via [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). So for instance:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(e[name]);
});
```

or with ES2015+:

```
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)) {
    console.log(e[name]);
}
```

Note that the "own" means that it doesn't include inherited properties, which `message` may or may not be depending on what JavaScript engine the code is running on. To get **all** of the object's string-named properties (ignoring Symbol-named ones), you need a loop looking at the prototype. You probably want to stop when you reach `Object.prototype`. So:

```
var obj = e;
while (obj !== Object.prototype) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(name => console.log(obj[name]));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN: A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable, non-Symbol properties. Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and String.prototype.